# Get Absolute Path of File in MVC with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, path

How do I get the absolute path of a file in MVC project with javascript. It always seems to look for the relative path of the view that is being displayed. How would get the absolute path?

Example

This: localhost:0/Project/Folder1/file1.jpg

Instead of: localhost:0/Controller/View/Folder1/file1.jpg

EDIT:

```
 var fileLocation = "folder1/file1.jpg"
```

Comment: How come you have a view folder inside a controller folder? that's not normal. Can you post the code that you have written that retrieves these paths?

Comment: That's not my exact code however it is similar. There is also a part where I use three.js plugin which also seems to get the relative path instead. Also that path is what shows up in my browser console. Not my actual path

Comment: That's not helpful. we cant help you if can't show us what you have written so far.

Comment: Actually I figured the issue out. So no more problems with the pathing. Sorry to bother you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was rather simple. I just needed to add the / in the front of the path.

```
var fileLocation = "/folder1/file1.jpg"
```

Sorry for the simple/stupid question!